# Budget program using dictionary

Tags: python-requests

1. Write a program that asks the user to enter the amount that he or she has budgeted for a month. A loop should then prompt the user to enter each of his or her expenses (title and amount) for the month, and keep a running total. When the loop finishes, the program should display the amount and inform the user that he or she is over or under budget. The program should also display Total expenses with their title.

Sample Output:
What is your budget for the previous month?
30000
Enter your expenses with their purpose/title 
Food items 5000
Any other expense? Y
Clothes 5000
Any other expense? N
Good Job! You saved 20000 from your previous month. Here are your details
Total Budget: 30000
Food items: 5000
Clothes: 5000
Remaining Budget: 20000
Thank You!

Comment: What's your question? Which part do you not know how to do?

Comment: budget=input("What is the budget of your previous month?")


dict={}
more_expences="y"
user_total_expences=0
total=0
i=1
while more_expences=='y':
    for i in range(more_expences=='y'):
        print("Enter your expences with their purpose and tittle")
        user_expences=input("Enter your expences with their purpose and tittle")
        price=input("Enter price of the title")
        dict[user_expences]=price
        more_expences=input("Do you want to contiue this then press y or n for no")   
        i+=1
print(dict)
total=sum(dict.values())
print(total) {output is not}